# Entity singularize Problem with tables having underscore ( _ )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, code-generation, edmx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPx6J.png)
I have a problem that newly created edmx doesn't singularize the table name having underscore ( _ ) in it.
The rest of the tables generate correctly.

Tried different solutions available on StackOverflow but no one properly describes how to handle underscores.

Unfortunately couldn't find any solution yet.

Table name: DF_DeletedVariables

Need to set:  DF_DeletedVariable

Comment: Well if it doesn't then it doesn't, nothing we can do about it. You can simply change the names in the EDMX, which will survive EDMX updates. And I would also remove this prefix. You don't want such database anomalies in your class model.